# Get A Custom Field From A Custom Taxonomy Of A Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

This has probably been answered before but I'm stumped so I'll ask anyway.

I have a custom post type called `products`. I then have a custom taxonomy called `product-category`. I've set up a custom field with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin on the product categories called `featured_image`. I've got a shortcode controlled function where the user supplies the slug like this `[ProductCategory product-category-slug]` and I want it to return the `featured_image`. This is the function I have:

```
function getProductCategory($cat){
    $return;
    $product_category = get_terms( 'product-category', array( 'slug' => $cat ) );
    $name = $product_category[0]->name;
    $image = $product_category[0]->get_field('featured_image');
    $return = $image;

    return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'ProductCategory', 'getProductCategory' );
add_filter('ProductCategory', 'do_shortcode');
```

This function is successfully retrieving the category, and I return the name is displays correctly. Now the problem is, I can't use `get_field()` in this way. How do I get the custom field?

Comment: Have you printed out the variables inside the $product_category ? I don't think get_terms() will return the field you want print_r($product_category);

Comment: Please stick with the [Advanced Custom Fields Support Forums](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'r using `ACF` plugin you should look the documentation first, [here's relevant](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/)

ACF saves taxonomies terms meta to options table, and they can be accesed using `get_field( "{$field_key}", "{$term->taxonomy}_{$term->term_id}" );`

So in you'r example it would be:

```
$image = get_field( 'featured_image', 'product-category_' . $product_category[0]->term_id );
```